# How to return value from a react native function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, return, boolean

I want this function to return boolean from this function but I am unable to do so. I am a newbie in react native and javascript.

```javascript
  checkBlocked(userId) {

    firebase.database().ref('Blocked/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userId).once('value').then(snapshot => {

        if (snapshot.exists()){
          var isBlocked = true;
        }
      else {
       var isBlocked = false;
      }
      })

      return isBlocked;

    }
```

Comment: You're not thinking async. `firebase.database()....once()` returns a promise. You can't just return a `true` or `false` if you need the result of the promise to decide if it should be `tru` or `false`. You have to return a promise that resolves with `true` or `false`

Comment: the answer below, that @aligumustosun gave, returns a Promise that resolves with `true` or `false`. You can use that value by either awaiting it in an async function, or passing in a `.then` callback: `checkBlocked(userId).then(val => this val is true or false)`

Comment: @TkoL thanks mate, I have to push these changes within few hours, would be a great help if you could write the code snippet in your answer *I am a noob at this*. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There isn't enough context for me to write anything for you. I don't know where you need the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
checkBlocked = async userId => {
  try {
  let snapshot = await firebase.database().ref('Blocked/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userId).once('value')
    return snapshot.exists();
  }
  catch(error) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Actually I want to return a "true" from this function for conditional rendering of a flatlist. I'm trying to filter out the posts of blocked users. Still can't achieve that. Please help!

Comment: Mate, I explained in my other comment that you cannot simply return a `true` or a `false` when async functions are involved. You cannot get around that -- you have to wait for the value to be returned from the api call before you can know if it was `true` or `false`.